# What is the oldest version of rubygems that is supported?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

What is the oldest version of rubygems that still allows you to download gems from rubygems.org?

Comment: I don't get your question... Supported by what? And why would you need gemcutter?

Comment: @Marc-André: Sorry about that! I think I was getting it mixed up with something else. Hopefully my question makes marginally more sense now. :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the transition from http://Gems.RubyForge.Org/ to http://RubyGems.Org/ was made, all backwards-compatibility features that were removed had already been replaced before RubyGems 1.0. So, you should be fine *at least* as far back as 1.0, possibly even further.

I'm not 100% sure, though. But I think that all that was removed was the YAML index format and bulk updating, both of which have been obsolete for years.